# Replace commas within parantheses using regular expression

Tags: sql, regex, python-2.7

I have a requirement in Python that I need to replace all the commas with a unique character, such as `"$"` or `"|"`, using regular expression. I tried doing so but not able to achieve my objective.

Please find below a sample string where I need to replace.

For e.g. consider the string below :-

```
SELECT 'column1' AS "Column 1" , 
  'column2' AS "Column 2" , 
  'column3' AS "Column 3", 
SUM(Column_1, Column_2) , 'column5' AS "Column 5" ,
CONCAT("str1","str2","str3") , 
ADD(len(str1),avg(column_1),sum(column_1,column_2,column_3))
```

In the above string i want to replace all the commas inside parentheses with "$" i.e.

```
SUM(Column_1 $ Column_2)
CONCAT("str1"$"str2"$"str3")
ADD(len(str1)$avg(column_1)
  $sum(column_1$column_2$column_3))
```

I have to do this with the help of regular expressions. I was able to do this for 2 values, means that when there is only one comma inside the ( ) I was able to replace but when tested with the scenario of more than one comma, my expression failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex like this? `(\s?,\s?)(?=[^\(]*\))|(\s?,\s?)(?=(?:[^\(]*\([^\(]*?\))*\))`

see: https://regex101.com/r/uT1gQ7/3

It matches the comma with optional spaces around it, if it is followed by `)` before another `(` appears, using **lookahead**, looking at level 1 deepness. The second alternative looks if the remaining string has an aditional `)` besides other `(stuff)` structures, It should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks much for the reply Andris. The solution you gave works partially for me. But it does not matches the first 2 commas in the below part which is inside the ADD function.

ADD(len(str1),avg(column_1),sum(column_1,column_2,column_3))

Comment: works like a charm now !! thanks a lot. I need to really learn a lot of this stuff.